# How do I prevent code from modifying the browser history?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the aspx setup. When I modify the DropDownList, an item is added to my browser's history, which results in unnecessary "back" clicks to escape the page.

How do I prevent aspx from modifying the browser's history?

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="RealTimeTracking.aspx.cs" Inherits="RealTimeTracking" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <title>Real Time Tracking</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function UpOneLevel() {
            window.location.href = "TableofContents.aspx";
        }
    </script>

    <link href="Calender/Style/calendar-blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script language="javascript" src="Calender/calendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script language="javascript" src="Calender/calendar-setup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Calender/lang/calendar-en.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="masterBody" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" runat="server">
    <h2 class="text">
        Real Time Tracking</h2>
    <h3 class="text">
        Select a Unit</h3>
    <h5 class="userinfotable">
        Phone:
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_PhoneValue" runat="server"></asp:Label></h5>
    <h5 class="userinfotable">
        Client:
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_ClientValue" runat="server"></asp:Label></h5>
    <asp:Label ID="lblErrormsg" runat="server" CssClass="words"></asp:Label>
    <table class="tbusernamepassword" style="text-shadow: none; color: Black; font-size: .9em; text-align: center;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="txtPleaseSelect" runat="server" CssClass="words" Style="padding: 0px;">
                    Please Select an Asset from the drop down menu.</asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" CssClass="vedispMsg"></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropSelectUnit" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropSelect_SelectedIndex"
                    OnLoad ="DropSelect_SelectedIndex"
                    DataTextField="Text" 
                    DataValueField="Value"
                    CssClass="tdsubmitbutton" Width="100%">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:Button ID="GoButton" runat="server" Text="Go To Map" OnClick="GoButton_Click" CssClass="tdsubmitbutton" Width="130px" />
    <p>
        &nbsp;
    </p>
    <p>
        &nbsp;
    </p>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" OnLoad="PingRateTable">
    <table class="tbusernamepassword" style="text-shadow: none; color: Black; font-size: .9em; text-align: center;padding-bottom:2px;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="words" Style="padding: 0px;">
                    Select a Ping Rate.</asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="vedispMsg"></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="PingRate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="PingRate_SelectedIndex"
                    OnLoad ="PingRate_SelectedIndex"
                    CssClass="tdsubmitbutton" Width="100%">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="PingButton" runat="server" Text="Set Ping Rate" OnClick="PingButton_Click" CssClass="tdsubmitbutton" Width="130px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="tbusernamepassword" style="text-shadow: none; color: Black; font-size: .9em; text-align: center;padding-top:0px;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="IsPingSet" runat="server" CssClass="words" Style="padding: 0px;"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <div style="visibility:hidden;">
        <input type="text" id="formlatitude" name="latitude" />
        <input type="text" id="formlongitude" name="longitude" />
        <input type="text" id="formassetname" name="asset" />
        <input type="text" id="formdatetime" name="dateandtime" />
        <input type="text" id="formaddress" name="address" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

codebehind C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Common.CheckAnyLogin();
    Session["Action"] = Request.Url;
    AssetHelper assethelp = new AssetHelper();
    IsPingSet.Text = "";
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
    }
}


protected void DropSelect_SelectedIndex(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender.GetType().Name == "DropDownList")
    {
        Session["UnitName"] = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedItem;
        Session["SerialNo"] = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;
    }
}
```

Master.master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<!--This master page encompasses all pages that require the user to be logged in.
This means that WhatIsThis.aspx, Logoff.aspx, Default.aspx,
 SearchForAsset-Map.aspx, MyLocation-Map.aspx,
 FleetTracking-Map.aspx, and AssetHistory-Map.aspx are not included in this masterpage.-->

<head runat="server">
<!--Apple iPhone and iPad compatibility-->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/splashscreen.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/Sights57.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<!--Microsoft Bing Maps-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0&s=1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-bing-maps/jquery.ui.bmap.js"></script>
<!--CSS and Javascript-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navbuttons.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/topofpage.js"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body style="min-height:391px;" runat="server" id="masterbody">
<form id="wholepageform" runat="server">
<div id="topofpage">
<!--#include virtual="header.html"-->
<div style="height:43px;"><br /></div>
<div class="undersightslogo" id="undersightslogo">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="body" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <div id="copyright"><h6>
    &copy; Reltronics Technologies <script type="text/javascript">document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script>
    </h6></div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

header.html is just a  containing my header, including my UpOneLevel button

Thank you.

Comment: you can not if you are doing a post back from the dropdown. If you changed this to ajax it should work.

Comment: how would i do this? i do have jquery

Comment: google and research...new question....

Comment: Can you tell us why you are storing the value in session when the drop down value changes? If you disable auto post back that is a start, however without knowing what you are trying to achieve it is difficult to provide the simplest solution. Yes ajax will work, however if you select an value and then submit it, that would also work depending on your scenario.

Comment: the session store is only so I don't have to do it later. I had another page that pulled sql data based on the drop down change, but this one doesn't need it. On submit, a map appears based on the selected dropdownlist.selectedvalue

Comment: So disable the autopostback and job's done. When you hit submit then you can save what you want to session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `AutoPostBack="false"` should resolve your problem.

Comment: Doing this would cause the server-side code to stop executing.  While it would "resolve" the problem asked, it would break other pieces of the OPs published code.

Comment: @SamAxe true, but it is the exact answer to the question. You're assuming that OP wouldn't be able to figure out an alternate way to do the rest by using an Ajax request for example. I've found most of the time (in life maybe not in SO) people just need help figuring out the code causing the problem and don't want the complete solution written for them.